# Print out every bit of variable like 0 or 1 in byte blocks

Tags: c++, printf, cout

I have a double variable.
Is it possible to output every bit of this variable using char*(char pointer) ?
So, char pointer would be

```
char* p = (char*)&myVar;
```

at the beginning and then it will be incremented to go through all the bits.

For example:

```
// double requires 8 bytes in the memory. 
double x = 8;
```

Should output something like:

```
00000000 00001010 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. The way things print would be implementation-defined, though - for example, `8.0` could end up looking like `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010 00000000`.

Comment: To be honest, Paul, the "duplicate" question shows solution using bitset and not a pointer.

Comment: @JoeSmith So read the `std::bitset` into your `char` array...

Comment: Never underestimate the simplicity of [a lookup table](http://ideone.com/iTosDI), easily generated with a half-dozen lines of code. Maybe overkill, but hard to argue with the triviality.

Comment: @WhozCraig, hm, that's pretty fun way of doing it, thank you!